# Combining two lists alternately

Tags: list, ocaml

Write a function that combines the two lists provided. Items in the output list are to alternate. You must not use library functions (e.g. "length", "reverse", "append") of complexity greater than O(1).

My code:

```ml
let rec zip(aList, bList) list = 
let rec first(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(aLst = []) then second(aLst,bLst)
     else aLst.hd :: second(aLst.tl, bLst)

 let rec second(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(bLst = []) then first(aLst,bLst)
    else bLst.hd :: first(aLst, bLst.tl);;

zip([1;2;3;4;5], [-6]);;
zip([1;2;3;4;5],[]);;
zip([-6],[1;2;3;4;5]);;
```

The problem:

`let rec second(aLst, bLst) list =`

Error: Syntax error

I'm also afraid of *rec* - is it gonna work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common recursive pattern for alternation is to swap the arguments in recursive calls, eg.

```
let rec zip a b =
  match a with
  | [] -> b
  | x :: a' -> x :: zip b a'                      (* swap arguments *)

zip [-6;-5;-4] [1;2;3];;
(* - : int list = [-6; 1; -5; 2; -4; 3] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a nested let is

```
let v = expr0 in expr
```

You forgot both the `in` and the final `expr`.

```
let rec zip(aList, bList) list = 
  let rec first(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(aLst = []) then second(aLst,bLst)
     else aLst.hd :: second(aLst.tl, bLst)
  in
  let rec second(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(bLst = []) then first(aLst,bLst)
    else bLst.hd :: first(aLst, bLst.tl)
  in
  first (aLst, bLst)
;;
```

Next problem is that `first` and `second` are mutually recursive. This requires the use of `and`:

```
let rec zip(aList, bList) list = 
  let rec first(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(aLst = []) then second(aLst,bLst)
     else aLst.hd :: second(aLst.tl, bLst)
  and second(aLst, bLst) list = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(bLst = []) then first(aLst,bLst)
    else bLst.hd :: first(aLst, bLst.tl)
  in
  first (aLst, bLst)
;;
```

Next what is up with `(aLst, bLst) list`? What is the "list" supposed to be there? Remove those across the board.

And last ocaml lists are not objects. Ocaml has objects but methods are called with `#`. Neither are lists records that have labels hd and tl. So `aLst.hd` makes no sense. You have to use `List.hd aLst` instead. Even better would be pattern matching but you don't seem to have learned about that yet.

Put it all together and you get:

```
let rec zip(aList, bList) = 
  let rec first(aLst, bLst) = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(aLst = []) then second(aLst,bLst)
     else List.hd aLst :: second(List.tl aLst, bLst)
  and second(aLst, bLst) = 
    if(aLst = [] && bLst = []) then []
    else if(bLst = []) then first(aLst,bLst)
    else List.hd bLst :: first(aLst, List.tl bLst)
  in
  first (aList, bList)
;;

# zip([1;3;5], [2;4;6]);;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other solutions have been offered, a late addition, but quite simple.

```
let rec zip = function
  | a, [] | [], a -> a
  | x::xs, y::ys -> x :: y :: zip (xs, ys)
```

In the event the second or first lists are empty, simply return the other list. This handles cases where *both* lists are empty and ensures the function gracefully handles lists whose lengths don't match.

In the case both have at least one element, interleave those two elements, and prepend them to the list created by recursively calling the function.

This runs in O(n) time, but stack space is also O(n). To reduce that to O(1) for space, as of OCaml 4.14 and later, we can use [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html).

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec zip = function
  | a, [] | [], a -> a
  | x::xs, y::ys -> x :: y :: zip (xs, ys)
```